# Five tables or a single table with an identifier column?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Do I go with:

#### Multiple Tables Method

```
   table5up             table10up                 table15up                 table20up             table25up
[id   -   name] [id   -   name   -   age] [id   -   name   -   age] [id   -   name   -   age] [id   -   name ]
[1    -   jhon] [1    -   mike   -   14 ] [1    -   alex   -   17 ] [1    -   mark   -   22 ] [1    -   felix]
```

Or

#### Single Table Method

```
[id  -  name  -  age   - up ]
[1   -  john  -  NULL  - 5  ]
[1   -  mike  -  14    - 10 ]
[1   -  alex  -  17    - 15 ]
[1   -  mark  -  22    - 20 ]
[1   -  felix -  NULL  - 25 ]
```

Knowing that I may have `NULL` values, which scheme, using 5 separate queries for multiple scheme:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table5up
SELECT id, name, age FROM table10up
SELECT id, name, age FROM table15up
SELECT id, name, age FROM table20up
SELECT id, name FROM table25up
```

Or one query defined by `up` column value for single scheme:

```
SELECT id, name, age FROM tableups WHERE up > 4 AND up < 26
```

I will not call all tables all the time, only one per time as example for multiple tables:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table5up;
```

and for single-table:

```
SELECT id, name, age FROM tableups WHERE up = 5
```

Props:

```
id INT(11), name VARCHAR(48), age TINYINT(3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables with the same structure but different sets of rows are sometimes called orthogonal tables. I don't believe in universal truths in the database world (which means: your use case could have peculiarities that I am not considering), but in general I consider orthogonal tables a bad idea.

From a theoretic perspective I can tell you that I especially don't like using metadata (table names) as data (age range). But what does it mean?

Tables designed in this way prevent you from running easily multi-table queries, like these:

```
SELECT AVG(age) FROM big_table;
SELECT up, COUNT(*) FROM big_table GROUP BY up;
```

Of course you will be able to obtain the same information with multiple queries, or with `UNION`. But it seems to me less clean and, should you ever need to add or remove a table, or change the usage of `up` (from 20,25,30 to 20,30,40), you'll need to make much more changes.

There are even more obvious case when the "one table" solution is better: maybe one day you'll need a query which returns people whose age is less than 23.

Flexible designs are usually better. For specific use cases, you can always create views, if really needed.

Comment: I'm confiused, really, What is the different in performance between big query with identifier `FROM bigtable WHERE up = 5` and a special query like `FROM table5up` exactly? in Utility the big one seems easier for me, But it may have `NULL` values in `age` for specific set.

Comment: I don't really see drawbacks related to `NULL`s in this case. You can use them in the one table solution and in the orthogonal solution, in both cases it won't affect performance. If your data is several millions of rows, running multiple queries on multiple tables could be faster (or not) - but the same result can be achieved by partitioning a big table. In less extreme cases, running 1 query is usually faster than running multiple queries, simply because you avoid to repeat multiple times operations like query parsing, query optimisation, transaction management, etc.